# JQuery - Problems with appendTo()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm moving elements from one list to another, the issue is:
I have javascript binded functions to the `<li>` depending of the `<ul>`, if I click one `<li>` that is inside an `<ul>` with an specific ID, a function is excecuted.

When I move the `<li>` with success, it's assumed the `<li>` is already in the other `<ul>` (The destination one). but if I click the `<li>` in the new list, the event still bind with the source one  `<ul>`

How do I do to bind the `<li>` with the current `<ul>`?

Thanks for your help.

```
<ul id="sourceList">
     <li>element1</li>
     <li>element2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="destinationList"></ul>

<script>

        $('#sourceList li').click(function () {
                $(this).appendTo('#destinationList');
                console.log("from source");
            });

        $('#destinationList li').on("click", function () {
            $(this).appendTo('#sourceList');
            console.log("from destination");
        });

</script>
```

Comment: En inglés por favor. Si no en http://es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize that, I'll move this question.

Comment: Anyway, here goes you answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events are binded when the script is executed the first time so, in your code, every `li` from `#sourceList` has a click event attached to the first defined event listener, no matter if you move the element to another container or not. You need to use event delegation for that:

```
$('#sourceList').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).appendTo('#destinationList');
    console.log("from source");
});

$('#destinationList').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).appendTo('#sourceList');
    console.log("from destination");
});
```

Comment: #MVP, Either `Google Translate` or just knows `Spanish` <3

Comment: Well, his profile says he's in Uruguay, so I would hope he knows Spanish. haha

Comment: LOL, it will be strange if i didn't